# Access type for deep method property using dot notation

Tags: typescript, class

Here's an example of a class with deep methods `S`.

```
class Core {
    read = () => true
}

class Customer extends Core {}
class Plan extends Core {}

class S {
    stripeCustomer = new Customer()
    stripePlan = new Plan()

}

type a = ReturnType<Core['read']> // boolean
type b = ReturnType<S['stripeCustomer']['read']> // boolean
```

This is the syntax I am looking for:

```
DeepMethodReturnType<A, B>

type c = DeepMethodReturnType<S, 'stripeCustomer.read'>
```

Is it possible to access the deep methods of a class using dot notation? like `stripeCustomer.read`?

Answer (score 0):

Not using dot notation unfortunately. String literals cannot be concatenated or split at the type level therefore this is impossible.

I.E This method would rely on splitting the string literal `stripeCustomer.read`
to `stripeCustomer` and `read` respectively.

You can however achieve similar syntax with tuples ["stripeCustomer", "read"]